# Getting error in running django hello world web server

Tags: django, django-views

When run server got following error. Please help

> Error "(test) C:\Users\91989\Projects\telusko>python manage.py
>   runserver Watching for file changes with StatReloader Performing
>   system checks...
>
> Exception in thread django-main-thread: Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File
>   "C:\Users\91989\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
>   line 590, in url_patterns
>       iter(patterns) TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:\python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()   File "c:\python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
>       self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "C:\Users\91989\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py",
>   line 53, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\91989\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py",
>   line 117, in inner_run
>       self.check(display_num_errors=True)   File "C:\Users\91989\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 392, in check
>       all_issues = self._run_checks(   File "C:\Users\91989\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 382, in _run_checks
>       return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)   File "C:\Users\91989\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py",
>   line 72, in run_checks
>       new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)   File "C:\Users\91989\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py",
>   line 13, in check_url_config
>       return check_resolver(resolver)   File "C:\Users\91989\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py",
>   line 23, in check_resolver
>       return check_method()   File "C:\Users\91989\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
>   line 408, in check
>       messages.extend(check_resolver(pattern))   File "C:\Users\91989\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py",
>   line 23, in check_resolver
>       return check_method()   File "C:\Users\91989\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
>   line 407, in check
>       for pattern in self.url_patterns:   File "C:\Users\91989\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py",
>   line 48, in **get**
>       res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Users\91989\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
>   line 597, in url_patterns
>       raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf
>   '' does not appear
>   to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then
>   the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

Comment: paste your `urls.py` file

Comment: from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('calc.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

Comment: update it on your q please, your next answerer will read it q section 1st before comment.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.urls import path
```

from . import views

urlpattern= [
    path('',views.home, name= 'home')

]

Answer (score 0):

```
urlpatterns= [ path('',views.home, name= 'home')]
```

You missed `s` at the end of URL patterns